# Saving a .CSV file to Google sheets from colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am reading from a Google sheets file in Colab, but I'd like to dump a pandas dataframe in its entirety to the colab. I've seen code snippets that deal with ranges, but I'd like some better way to "import" the entire CSV. Does anyone have the code for that?

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
sh = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')


worksheet = gc.open('A new spreadsheet').sheet1
```

When reading I have the following code:

```
rows = worksheet.get_all_records()
```

What is the equivalent for dumping a dataframe i.e. via `.csv`

I have tried writing rows as:

```
worksheet = gc.open('Capital Gain Output').sheet1
worksheet.add_rows(results)
```

where results is a list of dictionaries (one for each row).

For example, one website says try:

```
wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))
```

at https://erikrood.com/Posts/py_gsheets.html

However there is no method named that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a dataframe by converting it to a list of lists and pass it to `append_rows`. Apparently, `update` works too.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [4, 6, 5], [10, 20, 30]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df

     A   B   C
0    0   2   3
1    4   6   5
2   10  20  30
```

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

def write_google_sheet(df, sheet_name):
    sh = gc.create(sheet_name)
    worksheet = gc.open(sheet_name).sheet1
    worksheet.append_rows([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
    # worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
    print(worksheet.get_all_records())
```

```py
write_google_sheet(df, "testing sheet")

[{'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'A': 4, 'B': 6, 'C': 5}, {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first option is to follow your added link, you'll need to install [pygsheets](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), which allows you to read/write to the sheet through Python. Then you can use [set_dataframe](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=set_dataframe#pygsheets.Worksheet.set_dataframe) function with different parameters. For example:

```
#update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2. 
wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))
```

Another option is to use [gspread-dataframe](https://gspread-dataframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with a few lines you can write quickly your dataframe via [set_with_dataframe](https://gspread-dataframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=set_with_dataframe#gspread_dataframe.set_with_dataframe) function. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
from gspread_formatting.dataframe import format_with_dataframe

worksheet = `some_worksheet_obtained_from_gspread_client`

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'a': i, 'b': i * 2} for i in range(100)])
set_with_dataframe(worksheet, df)
```